# How much time(India) does it take for Salesforce to approve my Partner Portal login request for publishing app in AppExchange?

Tags: salesforce-support

[image: sfdc]

This is the error shown when accessing to the partner portal with my org credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that takes a variable amount of time, but typically takes something like 4-8 weeks. Your location is not important; everything has to go through a queue, as it depends on how many applications they have ahead of you. There's no real way to estimate, however. The process takes as long as it takes.

Comment: I am looking forward to become as an AppExchange Partner.Please enlighten me ,do I need to sit tight and wait for the approval or is there anything I am missing from my end?

Comment: @Maneesh unless they are waiting on you for something, you just need to be patient.